# Delay in JavaScript not by using settimeout

Tags: javascript

if i use setTimeout as following

```
setTimeout(function (){
   console.log("Delay");
}, 100);
```

But how do we know 100ms is the right amount of time for all computers in all conditions?

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` can be used to graphical stuff, but no delay.. You could have a start date and end date and then check in a interval, but you will never hit exactly 100ms for all computers.

Comment: I don't want to use the above setTimeout for animation.

Comment: What do you mean by "conditions"? Processing power?

Comment: @AshwinHegde: Then what are you using for? What is the "right" amount of time to do what?

Comment: If you are using it for animation, use `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: Is there any alternative that can be used for delay script/function/block of code execution without using setTimeout

Comment: @AshwinHegde As Blender already asked. What are you trying to accomplish with that? Maybe you can use a simple callback.

Comment: ok, i have some image upload operation,
I want to execute the console.log("delay"), after i upload an image ..this image can be very big this high resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a time-dependent system - apply a "benchmark" on the page and measure the time. For example, get time() in milliseconds, run a semi-heavy loop, then get another time() and calculate the differences between two times. Then you could use an array of compatible delay times for an amount of results.

Comment: According to your last comment it is not the solution for your problem. Once you handle an upload you never can tell the needed time for it depends on the network.

Comment: Yes, this could be a case.